# How to create a database in Mongo using Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have written the below Python program to create a MongoDB.

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')

mydb = myclient['mydatabase']

dblist = myclient.list_database_names()

if "mydatabase" in dblist:
  print("The database exists.")
else :
  print("The database does not exists.")
```

But while I execute the program , I get the result as

*The database does not exists.*

Why so? Is there something that I am missing ?

I am following the code mentioned in [W3Schools Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mongodb_create_db.asp)

Comment: I know it's stupid but... do you have mongodb running on localhost at port 27017?

Comment: yes ofcourse... i am following the guidance in the tutorial because I am new to Mongo, Python ..... and in 1 window - Mongo is running while in the other i am executing the python script (:

Answer (score 1):

Databases are lazily created. Insert something into a collection in that database and they (database/collection) will spring into existence.

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB the database is not actually created until you put some data into it, try put a document inside and check again.

> Important: In MongoDB, a database is not created until it gets content!